# C#: Thread safe function

Tags: c#

which of the following code is more appropriate situation where  multiple threads access the function

```
public ArrayList CallMe1()
    {
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

        lock(al.SyncRoot)
        {
            al.Add("33");
            al.Add("45");

            return al;
        }

    }

    public ArrayList CallMe2()
    {

        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

        Monitor.Enter(al);

        al.Add("33");
        al.Add("45");
        Monitor.Exit(al);

        return al;


    }
```

Answer (score 9):

There's no shared state in this case, so synchronisation is unnecessary.

However, assuming the arraylist **was** shared state, the following applies:

They're both the same ([lock implements Monitor internally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(VS.80).aspx)).

Mostly.

Your second version needs to release the monitor in a `finally` block, otherwise if the code throws an exception, the lock will never be released and will lead to deadlocks in your application.

In summary, use the first version (`lock (...) {... }`) to avoid unnecessary typing and possible mistakes.

Comment: ok ... actually the arraylist should be shared ... this was question in 70-536 exam which i just answered and cleared with a decent score of 950.. i had doubt regarding this one ...

Comment: considering the arralylist is shared ... which is a better code? i was puzzled with return with the lock{ return al;} i chose Monitor.enter and exit ... i remember checking on msdn the first one lock is used ..

Comment: Because lock implements a finally block, the return statement will still execute the contents of the finally block, therefore it will release the monitor.

Answer (score 8):

Neither. Functions don't share any data, so no syncronisation is needed.

Answer (score 6):

Neither. None of your functions have shared state (only local variables), which makes them inherently reentrant. No synchronization is required whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have stated lock uses monitor but it does it in a better way than your second example.  It's better in that it wraps calls to monitor in a try finally block ensuring that the lock is released if there is an exception.

For this reason I recommend that you use lock for nearly all operations.

Comment: what happens if there is a exception inside lock?

Comment: Given no exception are going to occur (as this was exam question), i chose monitor.enter and exit ... was i right?

Comment: I assumed that the code you posted was just a simple example and that you wouldn't really just be adding "33" and "45".  Therefor I assumed that there would be at least the possibility of a ArgumentNullException.

Answer (score 1):

1 - You don't need any lock here.

2 - Don't use Monitor if you can do it with a lock.

3 - In the first exemple, you are locking a SyncRoot object, it's better than locking on an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find a part of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266681/c-return-statement-in-a-lock-procedure-inside-or-outside).

Return statement inside (CallMe1) or outside (CallMe2) the lock makes also no difference.

Answer (score -2):

the problem with .net **lock** is that in case of a deadlock it is not going to throw any exception or anything.

By the way you are taking lock on a newly created ArrayList every time. How is that supposed to help? I prefer creating a static object somewhere and taking a lock on that.

Comment: Except if it's a static method. .)

Comment: That's not really a problem with lock. It's a problem with your code. Monitor doesn't handle deadlock as well.

Comment: @Svish - its not a static lock but lock on a static object.

Comment: @Martinho - you can use Monitor.TryEnter at least. Please refer to http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/03/23/locking