# Can I put a return statement inside a lock

Tags: c#, locking

**Dupe:** [return statement in a lock procedure: inside or outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266681/c-return-statement-in-a-lock-procedure-inside-or-outside)

The title is a little misleading. I know that you can do it, but I'm wondering about the performance implications.

consider these two blocks of code. (no error handling)

This block has the `return` outside of the lock

```
 public DownloadFile Dequeue()
 {
     DownloadFile toReturn = null;
     lock (QueueModifierLockObject)
     {
         toReturn = queue[0];
         queue.RemoveAt(0);
     }
     return toReturn;
 }
```

This block has the `return` statement *within* the lock

```
 public DownloadFile Dequeue()
 {
     lock (QueueModifierLockObject)
     {
         DownloadFile toReturn = queue[0];
         queue.RemoveAt(0);

         return toReturn;
     }
 }
```

Is there any difference in the code? I understand that the performance differences (if any) would be minimal, but I am specifically wondering if there would be a difference in the order that the `lock` gets release.

Comment: *Surely* this has been covered before?

Comment: I couldn't find the results because I wasn't using the right search terms before. Yeah, it's a dupe.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The C# compiler will move the return statement outside of the `try/finally` that is created for the `lock` statement.  Both of your examples are identical in terms of the IL that the compiler will emit for them.

Here is a simple example proving that:

```
class Example
{
    static Object obj = new Object();

    static int Foo()
    {
        lock (obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    static int Bar()
    {
        lock (obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bar");
        }
        return 2;
    }
}
```

The code above gets compiled to the following:

```
internal class Example
{
        private static object obj;

        static Example()
        {
                obj = new object();
                return;
        }

        public Example()
        {
                base..ctor();
                return;
        }

        private static int Bar()
        {
                int CS$1$0000;
                object CS$2$0001;
                Monitor.Enter(CS$2$0001 = obj);
        Label_000E:
                try
                {
                        Console.WriteLine("Bar");
                        goto Label_0025;
                }
                finally
                {
                Label_001D:
                        Monitor.Exit(CS$2$0001);
                }
        Label_0025:
                CS$1$0000 = 2;
        Label_002A:
                return CS$1$0000;
        }

        private static int Foo()
        {
                int CS$1$0000;
                object CS$2$0001;
                Monitor.Enter(CS$2$0001 = obj);
        Label_000E:
                try
                {
                        Console.WriteLine("Foo");
                        CS$1$0000 = 1;
                        goto Label_0026;
                }
                finally
                {
                Label_001E:
                        Monitor.Exit(CS$2$0001);
                }
        Label_0026:
                return CS$1$0000;
        }
}
```

As you can see, the compiler has taken the libery of moving the return statement in `Foo` outside of the `try/finally`.

Comment: Indeed. And if you go look at the generated IL, you'll see why we do that. You can only leave a protected region with a special "leave" instruction which knows how to clean up the exception handling goo (or, of course, by throwing an exception). You cannot do ordinary branches or returns out of a protected region. Therefore we have to generate leaves from the protected region to a return generated outside the region.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the IL would be identical... I'd have to test it to be fer sure, but the lock statement generates a try finally in the IL, and the return would trigger the finally (with the release) BEFORE the stack frame closes and returns to the caller anyway, so...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but why not use Dequeue?

Remember lock is simply shorthand for essentially something along the lines of:

```
        try
        {
            Monitor.Enter(QueueModifierLockObject);

            DownloadFile toReturn = queue.Dequeue();         

            return toReturn;
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(QueueModifierLockObject);
        }
```