# How to build x64 assembly project in visual studio 2017/2019

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86-64

The following code works when i set the 'debug' to 'x86'

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode: DWORD

.data
     ; define your variables here
.code

main PROC
    ; write your assembly code herer
    mov eax ,3
    mov ebx ,8
    add eax, ebx

   INVOKE ExitProcess ,0
main ENDP
END main
```

But does not work when i change 'x86' to 'x64'
[image: u]

it also fails if i try to use '64bit' register like rax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, please take a look at my article ["How to build a x64/x86-project with a standalone x64/x86 assembly file"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52803496/3512216).

Let's go through the error messages one by one (you can move the cursor to the errorneous line by double-clicking the error message):

> `A2008    syntax error : .                        test    main.asm    1`

The directive [.386](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/dot-386) is only allowed in 32-bit MASM (ML.EXE). It is not allowed in ML64 (ML64.EXE). ML64 "knows" all instructions which it can know.

> `A2008    syntax error : .                        test    main.asm    2`

The directive [.MODEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/dot-model) is only allowed in 32-bit MASM (ML.EXE). It is not allowed in ML64 (ML64.EXE). ML64 uses by default the flat model and the x64 calling convention (**not** C, BASIC, FORTRAN, PASCAL, SYSCALL or STDCALL).

> `A2008    syntax error : .                        test    main.asm    3`

The directive [.STACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59548353/stack-is-not-allocating-the-correct-size-in-masm) is a relic from the MS-DOS era. It's useless if you assemble with ML for Windows (Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59548353/stack-is-not-allocating-the-correct-size-in-masm)). It's not allowed in ML64.

> `A2008    syntax error : ,                        test    main.asm    4`

In the directive [PROTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/proto), ML64 doesn't like the comma between the PROTO keyword and the first parameter. Remove it.

> `A2008    syntax error : INVOKE                   test    main.asm    16`

The directive [INVOKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/invoke) isn't allowed in ML64 (yet). Replace INVOKE by a CALL and fill in the registers according to the [Microsoft x64 calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention):

```
mov ecx, 0
call ExitProcess
```

> `A2008    syntax error : main                     test    main.asm    18`
>   `A2088    END directive required at end of file   test    main.asm    18`

The directive [END](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/end-masm) must not contain an additional entry point for ML64. Remove "main". This also eliminates the second error. Set the entry point in the Visual Studio linker options according to [my article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52803496/3512216).