# C# List.Find() inside Parallel.ForEach Sometimes Returns NULL

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

With the below code, everything usually works fine. However, very rarely (once every month perhaps, when the code is run daily) the `.Find()` method can't find the item it's looking for.

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
names.Add("bob");
names.Add("henry");
names.Add("mary");

List<Person> peopleList = GetListOfPeople();

Parallel.ForEach(names, (name) => {
    Person personFound = peopleList.Find(p => p.Name.Equals(name));
    int varThatCantBeNULL = personFound.Age;
});
```

Occationally, `peopleList.Find()` will return an object but it's fields are NULL. How do I know this?

1. Re-running the application works without the problem re-occuring (no change in input or state that would change the content of peopleList)
2. Adding code to print the content of peopleList when the problem occurs reveals that an item exists in the list that meets the condition passed to `Find()` and it's fields are not NULL

I can't recreate the problem and have to wait for it to happen organically/naturally.

I'm assuming this is something to do with the parallelism and multiple threads trying to read from the same list. I've done a fix by catching the error and re-trying which seems to work.

**Can anyone offer insight into why this would happen?** I know writing to a common variable from multiple threads is problematic (race conditions) but I can't see why reading from a common list would cause issues.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the replies. All seem to suggest my use of `personFound` is not thread safe because other threads are writing to it (indeed there is code writing to the field I'm trying to access and having problems with).

However, this answer in this thread [Can I use local variables inside a Parallel Foreach loop (without unintentionally rewriting the previous value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61192617/can-i-use-local-variables-inside-a-parallel-foreach-loop-without-unintentionall)  would suggest that what I'm doing IS thread safe. Seems like bit of a contradiction. It does say ADO.NET classes aren't thread safe and I'm using a custom class not an ADO.NET one.

Comment: A better choice of data-structure might obliviate the need to fan this search onto multiple cores. The existing code, even in properly working form, is somewhat inefficient. Otherwise, how is the list maintained? Are contents changed from another thread?

Comment: Sounds like there is something writing to that list still, while other threads are reading. Reading is safe only if no thread ever writes to that list during the process.

Comment: @spender it's a simplification, the Parallel.ForEach is needed for other things as well. I'm open to changing the data structure used for List<Person> (in this example) but can't change List<names> or the Parallelism, as I think you're suggesting if I read that right?

Comment: Almost certainly the list is not always the same. This simplification is missing something that is in your actual code. Try copying the list into a new one, or even better into an array, before you do the Parallel.ForEach

Comment: Also, check that nothing else might have a reference to the Person objects in the list and changing them.

Comment: What you are effectively doing is an inefficient join. Even without a better data-structure, you could `peopleList.Join(names, p=>p.name, n=>n, (p,n) => p)` (a hash join), then parallel process the result list of person.

Comment: @Evk I edited my post to make it more accurate, sorry. It actually does return an OBJECT it's just it has NULL fields that I try to access. Same issue in effect.

I just double-checked using a ctrl & find and this list (peopleList) is only referenced twice: once during declaration and once when .Find is called. 

However, the object .Find returns IS written to!! but it's declared and used only inside Paralle.ForEach() so is only in the scope of the thread?!! Shouldn't be an issue?

Good to hear reading shouldn't be an issue as expected and I'm not crazy.

Comment: Suspect that is your problem. All threads sharing the same 'Person' references. So if changed in one place then all the threads see it. You need to do a deep copy on Person or else do some locking if you want to do something like this.

Comment: Variable `personFound ` is indeed declared inside a loop, but value it refers to is somewhere else. Nothing prevents some other thread to change `Person.Age` between your code finds it and the moment you access `personFound.Age`. Your `personFound` is just a reference to that value (available to be changed by anyone), not a copy. So in short - this is not thread safe

Comment: @spender Ah I see what you mean, yes that might be an improvement to efficiency. However, it's bit of a micro-optimisation and I find the current implementation easier to follow: foreach name, find the person's details. It's a bit more step-by-step. I've got to hand this over to people with little knowledge. You'll have to become an approver on our git repo before ill let u bend my arm on that point ;) but thanks for insight I didn't realise that was a valid option

Comment: @mikelegg thanks for reply, I edited the question, seems most likely but I'm just bit confused by contradictory info I'm reading online. Also examples I see online.

Comment: List<T> is  not threadsafe. *However, this answer...would suggest that what I'm doing IS thread safe* . No because that variable is enclosed inside the thread, your variable is not. That example and yours are not the same

Comment: @Evk Thanks for reply, I edited question. I'll need to go for a cold shower after all this talk of threading!! Googled it a bit more and found some contradictory posts on stackoverflow. Agree this is most likely the problem, everything points to it, this is just out of interest at this point

Comment: @Liam ah but, List<T> is not being written to inside the Parallel.ForEach. It's only READ from, so it not being threadsafe shouldn't be a problem? The variable personFound is what needs to be threadsafe?

Unless reading from the list in the way described is a problem in a thread which other replies suggest it shouldn't be?

Comment: I'm not sue what these *contradictory posts* but anything that says List<T> is thread safe is wrong. If you want a thread-safe collection there are [specialist classes for this purpose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/).

Comment: Yes but you also state *personFound .... **other threads are writing** to it*. If your **only** reading then your right, it's fine. If any other thread is writing to the same collection then you cannot guarantee the results of the read

Comment: @Liam thanks for link, I happen to be using some thread safe classes for collecting and reporting exceptions. Might need to use a similar collection for this List<T> if it comes to it. But question is, does a List<T> that is only being READ from need to be threadsafe? atm I'm thinking no

Comment: @Liam The threads aren't writting to the collection, they only write to the personFound variable, which is declared inside the thread and therefore the post I link suggests should be threadsafe? I feel like this is going round in circles a bit lol

Comment: I'd also question why you even need `Parallel.ForEach` here. I'd imagine this is actually slowing down you code not speeding it up. Unless `names` contains tens of thousands of records a normal `foreach` (or [linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64803808/c-sharp-list-find-inside-parallel-foreach-sometimes-returns-null#comment114576528_64803808)) is almost certainly more efficent

Comment: It's going round in circles because what you are describing is classic using a none thread-safe collection problem. If your certain that this collection is never written to out of sync then you shouldn't be having this problem, either way I'd just get rid of the `Parallel.ForEach` as it's almost certainly pointless

Comment: @Liam The parallel.foreach is for parallel data processing so that tables in a schema can be processed in parallel, parallelism is necessary to achieve our business requirements (there might be a way of achieving parallelism without this class but I couldn't find a better alternative). This blog describes the classing thread-safe collection problem, and I this code is different because of the assignment done during the .Find() : https://chrisstclair.co.uk/multithreading-made-easy-parallel-foreach/

Comment: Tell you what, lets flip this problem. re-write this without the Parrallel and ask yourself two questions, is it faster and does the problem go away. If the answer to both of these is yes then the solution is obvious

Comment: @liam without parallelism, the problem of the threadsafety goes away ofcourse, but it's not faster in my application because the concurrency saves hours worth of processing and this has been proven through testing and involvement of other more experienced people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said you never write to that list while reading - then reading itself doesn't cause any issues. All structures are thread safe when there are only readers and NO writers at all, that's why immutable structures are so popular - you cannot modify them so they are by design thread safe.

However, instead you are modifying fields of `Person` entries stored in the list, while reading those fields from other threads at the same time. This is of course not safe.

It seems you believe that

```
Person personFound = peopleList.Find(p => p.Name.Equals(name));
```

somehow creates a copy, and that subsequent access to `personFound` fields are guaranteed to return the same values they had at the moment you found it. That's not so, if `Person` is reference type (we can safely assume here it is).

There are two different "kinds" of types in .NET: reference types and value types. Variable of reference type kind of stores an address, and by following that address you can arrive to actual contents, which are stored somewhere else.

In your case - `personFound` varaible is indeed "local", however it just contains an address to the actual contents, and mentioned contents are changed by other threads. So when you do:

```
int varThatCantBeNULL = personFound.Age;
```

It rougly means - go to the location where `personFound` contents are stored and grab `Age` from there. At this point:

```
Person personFound = peopleList.Find(p => p.Name.Equals(name));
```

that Age might be not null, but before current thread had a chance to read `Age` in the next line - another thread could have modified it.

In the question you linked in edit - situation is not the same because they have

```
 string strType = drow["type"]
```

While string is also reference type - it's immutable and cannot be changed after creation (methods which "modify" string just create a copy, modify that copy and return it). So if `strType` contents cannot be changed by other threads.

Comment: Brilliant thanks. Only niggling query I have is, the code shouldn't be setting the value of personFound.Age to NULL at any point (it's not nullable and would result in a different exception at some point when it tries to set it to  NULL) so why Age becomes null is a mystery to me.  However, probably some quirk of the ordering of instructions or something similar and not worth worrying about. I'll change my work-around to something more elegant!! thank you sir, I would buy you a pint but I'm self-isolating.

Comment: 0

Good and helpful answer. On your last comment - what fields are you changing? The name by any chance? Are you sure it is Age that is null and not personFound? If no person is found in the list the result will be null.

Comment: *"All structures are thread safe when there are only readers and NO writers at all, [...]"* <== That's a brave statement to make. It is possibly true, but without having studied the source code of *all* structures it's hard to know for sure.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias if there are no writes then there cannot be thread-safety issues in principle. Studying source code can only help us know if there are really no writes (or better if docs tell us so right away).

Comment: The problem is that accessing the `get` accessor of an object's property (which makes you a "reader") does not guarantee that the internal state of the object will remain unchanged. The behavior of the getters is implementation-specific. So you *do* need to know the details of each and every implementation, if you want thread-safety without paying the cost of proper synchronization.

Comment: No doubt, you should be absolutely sure there are no writes. I only talk about situations where there are really no writes, not when you _assume_ that.