# Multiple threads with infinite loop and thread.sleep high CPU usage

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, console-application

In my console application I have some threads and each thread have an infinite loop with a Thread.Sleep.
Have many threads because each one is independent from others.
Each cycle is run every `waitingTime` time and I want that never stops.

```
static int waitingTime= 5 * 60 * 1000;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => Thread1());
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => Thread2());
    Thread thread3 = new Thread(() => Thread3());
    ...
    thread1.Start();
    thread2.Start();
    thread3.Start();
    ...
}

static void Thread1()
{
      do
      {
          // Connect to DB and do something...
          try
          {
              using (SqlConnection connection = MyDBClass.MyDBConnection())
              {
                  connection.Open();
                  SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                  command.CommandText = "SELECT x, y FROM Table WITH (NOLOCK);";
                  SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader();
                  while (sdr.Read())
                  {
                      MyObject obj = new MyObject(sdr[0] as string, ...);
                      MyStaticClass.SetMyObject(obj); // Open a new DB connection on different server and do an Update.
                  }
                  sdr.Close();
                  sdr.Dispose();
              }
          }
          catch
          {
          }

          Thread.Sleep(waitingTime);
      }
      while (true);
 }

static void Thread2()
{
     do
     {
        // Connect to DB and do something...
        Thread.Sleep(waitingTime);
     }
     while (true);
 }

...
```

I have read that is not good use Thread.Sleep() in cases like this and is suposes use solutions like [EventWaitHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/eventwaithandle).
What is the best solution for this case and how to implement that.

Comment: Your use case isn't clear. Why do you need `Thread.Sleep` at all? Why do you think `EventWaitHandle` will help you? Please elaborate.

Comment: Are you using multiple threads to improve performance? Database access is better addressed through asynchrony rather than parallelism.

Comment: Use a timer and look into asynchronous programming. Creating threads andf then making them sleep is a waste of resources...

Comment: @dymanoid ```Thread.Sleep``` is to makes the loop stop for waitingTime time. Using ```EventWaitHandle``` or ```AutoResetEvent``` is possible release CPU usage?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I use multiple threads to allow Thread1(), Thread2() ... code run independently from others. Can you tell me how is the best way to do that?

Comment: @Sponsor can you post your _Connect to DB and do something..._ code?

Answer (score 1):

A thread that is sleeping with `Thread.Sleep()` consumes zero CPU resources, so trying to improve on this using `EventWaitHandle` primitives or other means is pointless. You can't beat zero. What you could improve is the RAM consumed by the threads, which is [1 MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656872/why-is-stack-size-in-c-sharp-exactly-1-mb) for their stack, plus the memory they allocate on the heap (which depends on what they do while working). So by using a single thread instead of three you could reduce the RAM consumption by 2 MB or more, which for a console app running on a modern PC is practically nothing. So I wouldn't be concerned about it in your place.

Comment: Hi. There are a time where all my Threads are in Sleep and my CPU usage is about 10%. Sees you some reason for that?

Comment: @Sponsor they only thing I can think of is that the garbage collector is doing its job in its dedicated thread. It doesn't seem like a good explanation for a prolonged 10% CPU usage though.