# Single-threaded async/await in C# console app

Tags: c#, async-await, concurrency, task

By default in a console application, async Tasks will run on the `ThreadPool`, which means that multiple tasks can run in parallel on different threads (and will, if you have a multi core processor).

How can I disallow `Task`s  from running in parallel in my console application (without using a mutex; I don't want to have to deal with fairness issues and remembering to lock the mutex everywhere)? I'd like only one concurrent task to run at one time (i.e. I'd like the tasks to be concurrent but not parallel).

I've tried setting the max threads in the ThreadPool to 1, but the ThreadPool cannot be run with fewer threads than the CPU has cores, so that doesn't work.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255114/discussion-on-question-by-cherrypicked-single-threaded-async-await-in-c-console); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install a single-thread synchronization context on a Console application, using the static `AsyncContext` class found in the [AsyncEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx) NuGet package by Stephen Cleary:

```
AsyncContext.Run(async () =>
{
    await Foo();
    await Task.WhenAll(items.Select(async item =>
    {
        var result = await Bar(item);
        DoStuff(result);
    }));
    await FooBar();
});
```

The `AsyncContext.Run` is a blocking call, similar to the [`Application.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run) method. It installs a special `AsyncContextSynchronizationContext` on the current thread, much like the `Application.Run` installs a [`WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext) on the UI thread. As long as all `await`s inside the `AsyncContext.Run` delegate have the default configuration, meaning no [`ConfigureAwait(false)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait) is attached to them, all continuations after each and every `await` will run on the main thread of the console application. **Your** code will be single-threaded. Any built-in asynchronous methods might still use `ThreadPool` threads under the hood to do their work, but **your** code won't observe these other threads, and won't be affected by them.

The `AsyncContext.Run` completes when the asynchronous `action` delegate completes, along with any `async void` methods that might have been invoked inside the delegate. On the contrary any pending fire-and-forget tasks don't prevent the `AsyncContext.Run` from completing, and are left behind in a forever-incomplete state. After the completion of the `AsyncContext.Run`, the `AsyncContextSynchronizationContext` is uninstalled. The [`SynchronizationContext.Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current) reverts to its original state.

Be careful not to use `.Wait()` or `.Result` inside the delegate, otherwise your program will deadlock. If you block the one and only thread that executes your code, your program will grind to a halt.

Comment: Damn that was painful.

Comment: I am suspicious OP might _actually_ be running a hosted service...

Comment: I'm running whatever you get when you create a C# console application in visual studio.