# Forcing asynchronous tasks to wait for all ContinueWith operations to finish

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await

I am in the process of adding unit tests to some legacy code. There are critical operations that are handled in a `ContinueWith(...)` operation deep inside of a series of method calls. The tasks that execute in these method calls are not returned either, but instead executed with no `async/await` operations.

Is there a way to write a unit test that allows any/all `ContinueWith(...)` operations to finish before moving to the next line in my unit test? I'd like to avoid `Task.Delay()` operations in my mocks to solve this if possible.

Here is a quick demo of what I'm trying to do:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public async Task SomeTest()
{
   // assemble
   var backing = new Mock<IApiService>();
   backing.Setup(...);
   var service = new MyService(backingService.Object);
   var model = new Model { SomeValue = 1 };

   // act
   await service.DoStuffAsync(model); // <-- how to wait for all ContinueWith() calls?

   // assert
   Assert.AreEqual(2, model.SomeValue);
}
```

The code inside of `DoStuffAsync()` would look like this (*very* dumbed down):

```cs
public class MyService
{
   private readonly IApiService _api;

   public MyService(IApiService api)
   {
      _api = api;
   } 

   public async Task DoStuffAsync(Model model)
   {
      /* DO LOTS OF STUFF ASYNC & AWAIT HERE */
    
      var a = await _api.GetStuff(...);
      var b = await _api.GetMoreStuff(...);

      // ...

      // NOTE: this final call DOES NOT use async/await!
      // however, I need a test to ensure model (eventually) gets updated
      _api.PostAsync(...).ContinueWith(t => 
      {
         model.SomeValue = 2;
      });
   }
}
```

> Please ignore any compile errors, it's pseudo-code. :)

I'm wondering if there is a way to configure a (separate?) task in my unit test or something using a TaskFactory to only resolve after all continuations finish before moving forward. Is that even possible without refactoring the legacy code?

## Update

Thanks for all the feedback!! I took everyone's advice and updated the code to `async` / `await`. It was absolutely the right thing to do. Thanks again for the feedback!

Here is a quick overview of my approach:

```cs
public class MyService
{
   private readonly IApiService _api;
   private readonly Action<Task> _callback; // <== added this

   public MyService(IApiService api, Action<Task> callback = null)
   {
      _api = api;
      _callback = callback;
   }

   public async Task DoStuffAsync(Model model)
   {
      /* DO LOTS OF STUFF ASYNC & AWAIT HERE */

      var a = await _api.GetStuff(...);
      var b = await _api.GetMoreStuff(...);

      // ...

      // MY WORK AROUND TO SUPPORT UNIT TESTING
      // passed the model to another async method WITHOUT calling await
      // give the background task to my callback to await in the unit test
      var postTask = PostImplAsync(..., model);
      _callback?.Invoke(postTask);
   }

   private async Task PostImplAsync(..., Model model)
   {
      await _api.PostAsync(...);
      
      model.SomeValue = 2;
   }
```

Then, in my test I simply passed in a callback that took the task and awaited it, like this:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public async Task SomeTest()
{
   // assemble
   var backing = new Mock<IApiService>();
   backing.Setup(...);

   Task task = null; // <== ADDED THIS!!
   Action<Task> callback = t => task = t; // <== ADDED THIS!!

   var service = new MyService(backingService.Object, callback);
   var model = new Model { SomeValue = 1 };

   // act
   await service.DoStuffAsync(model); 
   await task; // <== ADDED THIS!!!

   // assert
   Assert.AreEqual(2, model.SomeValue);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any power to change the code? A very small change could make a big difference in making this testable.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do have the power to do this. However, I feel it's important to unit test "what is already there" before making my refactors. Again, this is "Legacy Code" and I'm in the process of changing it to a more maintainable design, but I need to write some tests to ensure I don't break anything or change it's existing behavior in any way.

Comment: There is value to a red/green/refactor cycle, but a compromise may be wise in this case. Your unit tests cannot perfectly capture existing behavior regardless. You'll be doing things synchronously that in a real environment would take much longer. If you use a custom Task Scheduler, then that makes the code behave differently from how it does in production. Plus, the current behavior isn't necessarily correct. With a small change to the code, you can make the behavior you want much more clear _and_ easier to unit test.

Comment: Depending on how you're mocking your services, it's likely that throwing an `await Task.Yield()` before your assertions would be enough to make your current test work. But I kind of hate to mention that because I don't think it's the right approach in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend replacing `ContinueWith` with `await`. Then not only are your unit tests reliable, but your application is, too.

The second-best solution is to introduce a "back channel" of asynchronous tasks as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77240715/263693).

If changing the code isn't an option, then you'll need to use Microsoft Fakes (or another injection framework) to intercept the calls to `ContinueWith` and delay completing the test until they have all completed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Swapping out `ContinueWith` to using `await` is not an option in this case. Again, my example code is elementary, and this code is much more time-critical to get back to the caller before the task completes. Is there a "short answer" to how I can configure a custom `TaskScheduler` in my  unit test to make all `ContinueWith(...)` actions to resolve with the main `await` in my simple test method?

Comment: @Luc: Read my answer again. You can use `AsyncContext` to do that.

Comment: Stephen are you sure that the `AsyncContext` is aware of fire-and-forget tasks? [Last time I checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77004994/single-threaded-async-await-in-c-sharp-console-app/77005961#77005961), it was only aware of `async void` methods (aka [fire-and-crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659603/async-void-asp-net-and-count-of-outstanding-operations/17660475#17660475 "Async Void, ASP.Net, and Count of Outstanding Operations")).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: Ah, you are correct! AsyncContext does provide a `TaskScheduler.Current` in addition to a `SynchronizationContext.Current`, which will be picked up by `ContinueWith`, but it won't actually be *scheduled* until the antecedent completes. :/  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you'd rather avoid changing the code you're testing, but it would probably be worthwhile if you can. Having unawaited tasks is generally a bad practice. If you want something to happen in the background, while the current action/request is allowed to complete, be explicit about putting it on some kind of [background task queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks).

```
   public MyService(IApiService api, IBackgroundTaskQueue backgroundTaskQueue)
   {
      _api = api;
      _backgroundTaskQueue = backgroundTaskQueue;
   }

   // ...

      await _backgroundTaskQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(async cancellationToken => 
      {
          await _api.PostAsync(..., cancellationToken);
          Model.SomeValue = 2;
      });
```

The background task queue can take care of tracking background tasks, logging in case of errors in those tasks, graceful cancellation in case your main application is trying to shut down. By using async/await consistently, you get better debugging and stack traces. And for unit testing, you can mock the task queue to test that PostAsync is called in the background task delegate, and that the model has one value before the PostAsync task completes and another one after the background task completes.

Comment: I didn't take the advice of using your suggested approach. However, you provided great feedback in regard to refactoring the code to full `async/await` for better debugging and stack traces.  I'm now presented with a _new_ problem though. I need to return to the caller as soon as possible and let the `PostAsync(...)` task work on it's own. The service has it's own thread management service and "awaiting" the `PostAsync(...)` to update the model (in my example) is not the correct approach. I'll update my answer to further explain. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @Luc: I think if you look at my answer carefully you'll find that it already takes your requirement into account. The `await PostAsync` is inside of a delegate that happens on a background task. The only thing your caller has to `await` is making sure that the background task gets _queued_. Once it's on the background queue, you return to the caller and trust that PostAsync will happen eventually.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you are searching for something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task SomeTest()
{
    /*...*/

    // act
    await MagicWrapperThatAwaitsAllFireAndForgetTasks(() =>
    {
        await service.DoStuffAsync(model);
    });

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(2, model.SomeValue);
}
```

The .NET infrastructure provides no mechanism that would make the `MagicWrapperThatAwaitsAllFireAndForgetTasks` method possible. Neither a specialized ambient [`SynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext) nor a specialized [`TaskScheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler) could be used effectively for this purpose. To explain way, lets look at a line from your example:

```
_api.PostAsync(...).ContinueWith(t =>
```

The asynchronous method `PostAsync` is fire-and-forget, and might complete a long time after the current method has completed. The `PostAsync` most likely is not implemented with async/await, in which case it ignores the current `SynchronizationContext`/`TaskScheduler`. So these schedulers receive no notification when the `PostAsync` starts or completes. So they can't be set in a standby mode, waiting for something to happen. They have no idea if something is happening or not. When the `PostAsync` completes, the `ContinueWith` will indeed notify the `TaskScheduler.Current`, but at that point it will be too late. The discontinuity caused by the `PostAsync` is what makes the whole idea unworkable.