# Async influence on other applications on the same host (IIS)

Tags: c#, iis, async-await

Assume I have 2 application hosted on `IIS` within the same machine.

`Application A` - very busy, has to serve lots of requests.

`Application B` - not busy at all, has to serve only few **but heavy** `IO` requests.

My question: If response time of `Application B` does not matter, does use of `async` in `Application B` save time for `Application A`?

I think, it may save time because when `Application B` will operate `IO` bound operation, if there is an `async` way `CPU` will not be suspended and waiting for the `IO` signal.

So, `Application A` would benefit from it. But I'm not sure if I'm right about it. Or, the impact is only on other threads within the same application (i.e. `Application B`).

Can someone clarify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `async` in Application B will make it use less threads, and since each thread requires [1MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656872/why-is-stack-size-in-c-sharp-exactly-1-mb) for its stack, the memory used by the Application B will be reduced. Since the Application B is not busy, the number of threads it uses is probably already small, so I expect that switching to async will have negligible effect to the whole system.

Btw there is no such thing as "suspended CPU". You can [suspend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.suspend) a software thread, not a CPU. The CPUs are managed by the operating system.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If for some reason `Application B` will be busy too, does it influence now or every application has its fixed memory slice?

Comment: @Roni I am not really sure. Maybe the IIS has some option to restrict the memory used by each application. But if both applications are busy, then the memory may not be the only possible contended resource. The CPU, or the network bandwidth, or the storage I/O could be saturated too.