# Timeout on CreateRequestClient on volume test after MassTransit upgrade

Tags: c#, timeout, masstransit

Just upgraded from MassTransit 6.3.2 to 7.2.4.  I'm using .Net Core 5.

The following unit test works fine before the upgrade but fails after.

```
using var harness = new InMemoryTestHarness();
       
harness.Consumer(() => new MockedxxxService(), xxxEndPoint);

harness.Start().Wait();

IBus endpoint = harness.Bus;

var tasks = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<Task<string>>();
var result = Parallel.For(0, 100, index =>
{
    var sut = new xxxRetriever(..., endpoint, ...);
    tasks.Add(sut.Getxxx(paramx));
});

Assert.True(result.IsCompleted);

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

The code in the xxxRetriever class looks like this.

```
public async Task<string> Getxxx(string paramx)
{

   try
   {
      var serviceAddress = new Uri("queue:" + ...);

      var xxxService = _busService.CreateRequestClient<xxxContract>(serviceAddress, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(xxx));
       var xxxResponse = await xxxService.GetResponse<xxxResultContract>(new
       {
           ...
       }).ConfigureAwait(false);

     ....
   }
}
```

The endpoint is injected into the class as an IBus.

The mocked service looks like this.

```
public class MockedxxxService : IConsumer<xxxContract>
{

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<xxxContract> context)
    {
        await context.RespondAsync<xxxResultContract>(new { ... } } });
    }
}
```

The tests run fine when we limit the number of tasks to about 30.  But above that it fails consistently with the message "Timeout waiting for response, RequestId: ...".

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to contention in the TPL, but that would only be a guess. You might be able to configure increase the concurrency limit on the bus and see if that helps:

```cs
harness.OnConfigureInMemoryBus += c =>
{
    c.Host(h => h.TransportConcurrencyLimit = 100);
};
```

> That's a guess, but it might be related since it's load specific.

Obviously, this should be called prior to calling `Start` on the hardness (which should be `await`ed, instead of using `.Wait()` by the way).

Comment: Thanks for the response and the suggestion.  However, that didn't work.

Comment: If you create a standalone GitHub repository that reproduces the problem, you can submit an issue.

Answer (score 0):

After much investigation, we found that this was caused by the way .Net 5 handles thread creation.  See [ThreadPool.SetMinThreads does not create any new threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68965175/threadpool-setminthreads-does-not-create-any-new-threads)

We primed the thread pool before the test and that fixed the issue.  Not sure why this worked correctly in .Net 5 under MassTransit 6, but it's working now.