# all of my .NET Console application process showing up in RAMMAP on the server with 4K Private Bytes

Tags: c#, .net, process, console, zombie-process

I have a lot of console applications that run in a scheduler every 10 mins, I see the console applications are completing successfully, all the objects in the code are closed and disposed as needed. I ran processexplorer, perfview, process monitor and was not able to identify any applications hanging around.

But I see all my applications (1000's of them) are showing up in RAMMAP process section all of them with 4K Private bytes, please see screen shot attached.

Please advise is this normal or do i have a potential leak in all my applications? any tool that can be recommended to identify/resolve this issue?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Maybe because each application has Thread and each thread has allocated memory for [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656872/why-is-stack-size-in-c-sharp-exactly-1-mb).

Comment: All processes have at least one thread - pretty much by definition.  In a pure .NET app, a process will not quit until all threads not marked as _background threads_ have exited.  Any single non-background thread will keep the process alive.  The app may appear to quit, but it is still running.  It should, however, show up in something like Task Manager when it's in that state (I think).

Comment: I have checked in Task Manager and as i mentioned in the process explorer as well and these apps are not showing up there, it is only showing up in RAMMAP. This is a console application and we have added extensive logging to make sure the application has ended with no errors and looks good in the log that the application has ended, but why then it is still appearing in the background thread? what is keeping this alive?

Comment: @Javeed did you solve this ? I have a .net 4.8 console app with same problem. The issue occurs only when it calls a database through Entity Framework.