# Should a Return statement be outside of critical section?

Tags: c, operating-system, locks

I am taking an operating systems course. I would like to ask about Locks and critical section. Consider the following `C` function that can be called by multiple threads. I use a lock whenever the shared resource `balance` is used.

```
int withdraw(account, amount) 
{
     acquire(lock);
     balance = get_balance(account);
     balance = balance - amount;
     put_balance(account, balance);
     release(lock);
     return balance;
}
```

My question is should I do it like that or should I release the lock after the `return` statement? What are the consequences of either way and which of them is a better practice?

I saw another similar [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266681/should-a-return-statement-be-inside-or-outside-a-lock) but it I couldn't understand from it what is the proper thing to do in my example case.

Comment: How is the lock supposed to be released if that line is after the return?

Comment: Can you post the alternative that you have in mind?

Comment: @warning the other question use c# and the lock is removed at the end of the {} after it, you you are in C and you need to unlock explicitely

Comment: @bruno - could you explain why again? i still don't get it

Comment: @Orb what do you not get ? the fact the lock is automatically cancel in c# ? I see you accepted the answer, it is not enough clear ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question you linked to is about C# code, not C. In C#, the lock is automatically released when you return from within a `lock` block. In C, there is no `lock` statement. You always need to release it yourself. If you return from within the critical section, the lock will not be released, because none of the statements that come after a `return` statement will be executed.